# C++ vectors of classes with constructors

Tags: c++, class, constructor, vector

```
//Using g++ and ubuntu.
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```

Define a class:

```
class foo(){
(...)
foo(int arg1, double arg2);
}
```

Constructor:

```
foo::foo(int arg1, double arg2){ 
(...) //arrays whose length depend upon arg1 and arg2
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
vector<foo> bar(10); //error: no matching function for call to 'foo::foo()'
bar[0] = new foo(123, 4.56);
(...)
```

An alternative method (which I like less) is to use push_back:

```
vector<foo> bar; //works
bar.push_back(new foo(123, 4.56)); //throws similar error.
//Omitting the "new" compiles but throws a "double free or corruption (fasttop)" on runtime.
```

I want different elements of the vector to be constructed differently, so I don't want to use the "Repetitive sequence constructor".
What should be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using `new` when no dynamic memory needs to be created? Of course using `new` will fail, it results in a `foo*` when `push_back` accepts a `foo`. (That's what you have a vector of, after all.)

What's wrong with `push_back`? If you want to reserve memory up front, use `reserve()`; providing a number in the constructor of `vector` makes that many copies of the second parameter (which is implicitly `foo()`, which won't work hence your errors), which isn't the same as simply reserving memory.

If doing things correctly (no `new`) crashes, the fault is in your code and not vector. You probably haven't written a proper class that manages resources.* (Remember [The Big Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), use the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).)

<sub>*I say this because you say "`//arrays whose length depend upon arg1 and arg2`
", which I suspect means you have `new[]` in your class somewhere. Without the Big Three, your resource management will fail.</sub>

You shouldn't be managing resources anyway, classes have one responsibility. That means it should either be a dynamic array, or use a dynamic array, but not both manage and use a dynamic array. So factor out the resources into their own class, and then make another class (yours) which uses them. A dynamic array is a `std::vector`, so you are already done with that. *Any* time you need a dynamic array, use a `vector`; there is never a reason not to.

Comment: +1 for a really good answer. If I could, I would like to give an additional +1 for not saying that you should always use std::vector, but that you should always use a vector.

Answer (score 5):

```
vector<foo> bar(10); //error: no matching function for call to 'foo::foo()'
```

This is failing because the `std::vector` constructor you're calling is

```
explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

As you can see, it is trying to fill the vector with 10 calls to the default constructor of `foo` which does not exist.

Also, all your examples featuring `new` will fail because the vector is expecting an object of type `foo`, not `foo *`. Furthermore, changing to `vector<foo *>` will fail too unless you manually `delete` every member before clearing the vector. If you really want to go the dynamic memory allocation route create a `vector< shared_ptr< foo > >`. `shared_ptr` is available in the [Boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/shared_ptr.html) or if your compiler includes TR1 libraries it'll be present in the `<memory>` header within the `std::tr1` namespace or if your compiler has C++0x libraries it'll be available in the `std` namespace itself.

What you should probably do is the following:

```
vector<foo> bar;
bar.reserve(10);
bar.push_back( foo( 1, 2 ) );
...
...
bar.push_back( foo( 10, 20 ) ); //10 times
```

Comment: Probably should mention that shared_ptr is a part of the boost libraries or C++0x

Comment: @Kevin: I suspect you should use `std::vector` so you don't. Do factor resource from usage, do not do both.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector always create elements based on the default constructor which you haven't define in snippet above.

the push_back method is facing a double free issue because you did not handle the copy constructor.